# Subclass instantiation | Stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, stack-overflow, subclass

I got a lot of code, but the problem itself is very clear to me so I'm posting an example:

```
public class ExcelTable
{
    public ExcelTable() // CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        // create new excel-application and so on..
    }

    public ExcelOutput Output = new ExcelOutput(); // Stackoverflowexception

    private xlWorkbook;  // I need these to inherit into ExcelOutput
    private xlWorksheet; // ''    ''
    // ...               // ''    ''

    public class ExcelOutput : ExcelTable
    {
        public void SaveAs()
        {
            // self explaining
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            // self explaining
        }

        public void Print()
        //....
    }
}
```

**Goal: *EDITED***
In purpose of a clear helping-class for excel my wish is to create a subclass which takes care for the possible output. In detail I'm trying to prevent the need to create 2 instances from outside => `ExcelTable` and `ExcelOutput`. Im rather would like to create a single instance `ExcelTable` and access the subclass with this instance. Because I need the inheritance, I cant set the class to static.

**Problem:**
Im getting a `Stackoverflowexception`. I tried debugging my code. At the instantiation of `ExcelOutput`the code is looping at this single line. Means: Even if I try to Single-Step (F11) it, the execution stays at the instatiation of ExcelOutput which leads my tool to the Stackoverflowexception.

**What I've tried:**

```
public ExcelTable() // CONSTRUCTOR
{
    // create new excel-application and so on..

    Output = Output ?? new ExcelOutput();
}

public ExcelOutput Output;
```

In this case, `ExcelTable` is created over and over again. This whole upper class gets instatiated for ever.

So could anyone explain to me why this single line is looping forever? It looks like the instantiaton of `ExcelOutput` is creating a new instance of `ExcelTable`.

---

I know this is more about knowledge as Im a newbie in case of inheritance and subclasses. Google wasnt a big help in here. There's just too much stuff out there according classes, subclasses and inheritance.

Every help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `ExcelOutput` inherits from `ExcelTable` so it will inherit the `Output` variable.

Comment: @YacoubMassad oh yeah, true thing I havnt thought about. But is this already causing my problem?

Comment: @C4ud3x, yes, that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: I've edited the `Goal:`-Part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, the problem is that `ExcelOutput` inherits from `ExcelTable` and thus inherits the `Output` field which is initialized with a new instance of `ExcelOutput` which again has an `Output` field ...

This recursive composition will fill the stack and thus cause the `StackOverflowException` exception.

Here is a quick fix that will get you going:

```
public class ExcelTable
{
    public ExcelTable() 
    {
        // create new excel-application and so on..
        //initialize xlWorkbook and xlWorksheet

        Output = new ExcelOutput(xlWorkbook, xlWorksheet);
    }

    public ExcelOutput Output;

    private Workbook xlWorkbook;
    private Worksheet xlWorksheet;

    public class ExcelOutput
    {
        private Workbook xlWorkbook;  
        private Worksheet xlWorksheet;

        public ExcelOutput(Workbook xl_workbook, Worksheet xl_worksheet)
        {
            xlWorkbook = xl_workbook;
            xlWorksheet = xl_worksheet;
        }

        public void SaveAs()
        {
            // self explaining
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            // self explaining
        }

        public void Print()
        {

        }
        //....
    }
}
```

`ExcelOutput` no longer inherits from `ExcelTable`, but it receives the required dependencies upon construction.

My solution is in no way a good design. I am just giving you a quick fix. A good design would require an understanding of the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a ExcelTable or ExcelOutput the constructor will initialize the Output field, in other words, it will instantiate another ExcelOutput, and then again and again until you run out of stack space, then you receive this StackOverflowException, you probably doesn't need the Output field, remove it.

Comment: But when I remove my field `Output` I cant access `ExcelOutput` from outside without creating a new instance there!?

Comment: @C4ud3x, if it is supposed to be a singleton (a single instance in the entire application) you can modify the field to add a "static" to it, then it will be possible to access it by ExcelTable.Output, if many instances are needed then just instantiate by new ExcelTable.ExcelOutput(), or move the ExcelOutput class to outside the ExcelTable class.

Comment: Yeah another point I already thought about. But when I set the `ExcelOutput`-Class to static, I cant use the inheritance, cant I? Without inheriting my variables I would have to pass my `excelWorkbook`, `excelWorksheet` and so on to all function. Would be a mess....

Comment: I think you are messing a few concepts here, do you expect to set xlWorkbook on ExcelTable and read it from ExcelOutput? You won't, inheritance doesn't work like this, when you inherit a class you inherit it's "prototype", not any data or specific instances, to start with, you don't really need 2 classes for your goal, could you provide the rest of your code?

Comment: Aaaaaaah. Alright. Now I understand why this happend. Because the structure itself is inherited, which creates a new instance. Thanks for clearing this! I've managed to get it working as wished with a constructor inside `ExcelOutput` which gets the data from `ExcelMappe`. Could you append your comment to your answer? I would accept it then.`