# "Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException", reason for it in the following code

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

A class which in it of itself contains its own object instantiated,when creating an object of that class in main method in c#, it gives stackoverflowExeption. Why?? I want the reason for it, not the solution.Thanks

```
namespace project_1
{
class check
{
    check checkobject = new check();// Line-1

    /*I have not access Line-1 in main method.
     But due to Line-1 or Line-2, output says "Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException". Why??
     I do not need the solution, I want to know the reason for it.
     Removing " new check() " from Line-1, then it works fine.
     */
    public void Display() {
        Console.WriteLine("It worked");
    }
}
class DemoProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        check ob1 = new check();// Line-2
        ob1.Display();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're recursively instantiating the class so you run out of stack memory. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182621/10531996

Comment: The problem is that it is infinetly creating more and more instances

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you create a new check object from your main method, it triggers the initialization of the instance variable, `checkobject`, which again creates an object of class check. This is an infinite procedure, hence the memory alloted to your program is exhausted.

Comment: @PrakharLondhe he cannot upvote the answer but he can accept it.

Comment: @dan1st Ohh okayy , I forgot the priviledges :P

Comment: Accepting brings you more reputation anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You call your class constructor every time the class is initialised. The line marked as line 1 is the one you shouldn't have. It means you call your constructor recursively.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to [*debug*](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online/) your program, you see the similar output to the following. If you know almost nothing why it happens, at least you can guess something is wrong subject to the constructor.

```
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

jdoodle.cs(5,11): warning CS0414: The private field `check.checkobject' is assigned 
                  but its value is never used


Stack overflow: IP: 0x5647646e1705, fault addr: 0x7fffc422eff8
Stacktrace:
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper alloc) object.AllocSmall (intptr,intptr) <0x00103>
  <...>
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0
  ........
  ........
  ........
  ........
  ........
  at check..ctor () [0x00000] in <db1fd2bd96e041fab014c4ec28898e03>:0

  output Limit reached.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an *endless recursion* caused by a *field initializer*.

**Example**

```
public class Test
{
   Type FieldName = SomeValue;
```

A *field initializer* is executed before constructor bodies. The important take-home point here is, they are **always** executed.

Which means you **can't** do this, it runs when the *class* initialises.

```
check checkobject = new check();
```

Every time you *new* up (initialise) this *class*, it's going to run the above code, which by its very nature new's up another instances of itself due to the *field initializers, which in-turns runs the above again *so-on-and-so-forth* until you run out of *stack*.

If you really want a *self-referencing* property like this, and you want it initialised (in an automatic sense), use a lazy loading technique, eg.

```
private Check _checkObject;

public Check CheckObject => _checkObject?? (_checkObject = new Check());
```